# Codeigniter Xampp Remove index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a sipmle php application on my local server. I am using xampp. I am trying to remove index.php from my urls. I have checked many articles, documentations and questions on the internet and tried all of them but never worked. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and I have modified these lines on config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and modified httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost:8080

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

...

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Projeler"
<Directory "C:/Projeler">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this htaccess below windows xampp

project > .htaccess make sure file out side of application folde

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Some more htaccess here https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter